# Use of partition

Tags: oracle10g, partitioning

When to partition table in Oracle??

Comment: Why not create another table instead of partition??

Comment: Because with partitioning you still have one logical table; you can add and remove partitions without having to change any application code or other SQL that accesses the data.

Answer (score 1):

A number of reasons for partitioning a table are detailed [in the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm#CACJFBEB).